# Query results with no reverse

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ive got table:
UserA,
UserB,
numberOfConnections

I would like to write query which returns me only rows that has no reverse I mean or example :
for data :

```
1 2 10
1 3 10
1 5 10
1 6 10
2 6 10
2 5 10
5 1 10
5 2 10
3 1 10
```

it should return

```
1 2 10
1 3 10
1 5 10
1 6 10
2 6 10
2 5 10
```

rows:

```
5 1 10
5 2 10
3 1 10
```

arent valid because there are already corresponding

```
1 5 10
2 5 10
3 1 10
```

thanks for help
bye

Comment: would you like to do this as sql or as c# Code?

Comment: Does it matter which of the pair you get?

Comment: Is the relation 1:M in the same table and you want the parent rows to be displayed? Oops sorry now i understand the question.

Comment: I came up with a solution dude, check it out

Comment: If I understand correctly, you consider 

          dice| marbles | peanuts

a duplicate of

          marbles | peanuts |  dice


That is, it doesn't matter which column the values appear in.  The column values are thrown into a bag, so to speak, and you want the unique set of bags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want

```
SELECT mt1.UserA, mt1.UserB, mt1.numberOfConnections
FROM MyTable mt1
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable mt2 ON mt1.UserA = mt2.UserB
        AND mt1.UserB = mt2.UserA
WHERE mt2.UserA IS NULL
    OR mt1.UserA < mt2.UserA
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add UserA < UserB in where clause. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
with t1 as (
select col1 ,col2,
     row_number() 
      over(partition by case when col1>col2 then col1+col2 else col2+col1 end 
           order by case when col1>col2 then col1+col2 else col2+col1 end) as rownum 
from table_1 )

select * from t1 where rownum =1
```

if your data type of col1 and col2 are not `varchar`, just `cast` them

you can replace the `row_number` by `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Use **Updated**

A- Result No Reverse

```
Select UserA, UserB, numberOfConnections
From TName
Where ID Not IN(
SELECT t1.ID
FROM TName As t1 INNER JOIN TName As t2 ON (t1.UserA = t2.UserB) AND (t1.UserB = t2.UserA))
```

B- Result Reverse Only Repeted

```
Select UserA, UserB, numberOfConnections
From TName
Where ID IN(
SELECT t1.ID
FROM TName As t1 INNER JOIN TName As t2 ON (t1.UserA = t2.UserB) AND (t1.UserB = t2.UserA))
```

C- Result Reverse Only Not Repeted

```
Select UserA, UserB, numberOfConnections
From TName
Where ID IN(
SELECT t1.ID
FROM TName As t1 INNER JOIN TName As t2 ON (t1.UserA = t2.UserB) AND (t1.UserB = t2.UserA) and (t1.UserA<t1.UserB))
```

D- Result No Reverse and  Not Repeted Reverse

A
Union
C